# Is assigning a bound function to a var really the only option?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Given the Object below, is `this.delegateBind = this.delegate.bind(this)` my only option when dealing with event listeners and this?  I've read other related questions that suggest this is the proper pattern, but it seems inelegant...  Is there a more succinct pattern I'm missing?

```
const foo = {
  init: function(btn){
    this.btn = btn
    this.delegateBind = this.delegate.bind(this)

    btn.addEventListener('click', this.toggle.bind(this))
  },
  toggle: function(e){
    console.log('do stuff')

    if(something){
      document.body.addEventListener('click', this.delegateBind)
    }else{
      document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.delegateBind)
    }
  },
  delegate: function(e){
    switch(true){
      case e.target.matches('.btn-close'):
        this.btn.click()
        break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you could use a class or arrow functions

Comment: @floor wouldn't arrow functions result in global object props?

Comment: yes if you make the object properties arrow functions but no if you do something like this: btn.addEventListener('click', () => {this.toggle();}) so inside property functions you pass an arrow function which has the correct this bound to it. you could also set a variable var self = this and pass self around the functions.

Comment: Thanks @floor for the suggestion/clarification - I tested and 2 issues come up when using arrow functions in the event listener: 1) reference to the original event is lost - not a deal breaker since we can pass ref down: addEventListener('click', (e) => this.delegate(e)).  But 2) is that I can't remove the event listener anymore since it's essentially an anonymous function.  I appreciate the suggestion tho!

Comment: no problem, but it is completely possible to remove the event listener... i'll leave you with that and you can research if you want.